# mysql: need to avoid storing temp tables on binary logs

Tags: mysql, binary-log

On mysql,  I have two data bases "parque_test" and "tabelas_temporais", and binary logs are activated.

Every action that modifies an InnoDB table belonging to "parque_test" is recorded on the binary log. However, "parque_test" has stored procedures that use temporary tables to retrieve a result (they are not used to perform update, delete or insert).

To avoid recording the activity of the temporary tables on the bin log, I have set the 
"/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file so that mysql register all the activities on "parque_test" with the exception of "tabelas_temporais".

`cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf"`

`...`

`#log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log`

`log_bin=/mysql-log/bin-log`

`binlog_do_db=parque_test`

`binlog_do_db=parque_prod`

`expire_logs_days   = 10`

`max_binlog_size         = 100M`

`#binlog_do_db      = include_database_name`

`#binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name`

`binlog_ignore_db=tabelas_temporais`

`...`

All the temporary tables are created on the "tabelas_temporais" schema; however, the binary log still records the activities on "tabelas_temporais" when for example a stored procedure from "parque_test" is executed a containing a command such as

`DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tabelas_temporais.temp_mod_user;`

Any help would be much appreciated!

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database filtering in the MySQL binary log can be somewhat unexpected if you don't know exactly how it works. [from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-ignore-db)

> When using statement-based logging, the following example does not work as you might expect. Suppose that the server is started with `--binlog-ignore-db=sales` and you issue the following statements:
>
> `USE prices;UPDATE sales.january SET amount=amount+1000;`
>
> The `UPDATE` statement is logged in such a case because `--binlog-ignore-db` applies only to the default database (determined by the `USE` statement). Because the sales database was specified explicitly in the statement, the statement has not been filtered. However, when using row-based logging, the `UPDATE` statement's effects are not written to the binary log, which means that no changes to the `sales.january` table are logged; in this instance, `--binlog-ignore-db=sales` causes all changes made to tables in the master's copy of the sales database to be ignored for purposes of binary logging.

In short: it seems you might want to look into `ROW` based logging instead of `STATEMENT` or `MIXED`. However:

> You should keep in mind that the format used to log a given statement may not necessarily be the same as that indicated by the value of binlog_format. For example, DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE are always logged as statements, without regard to the logging format in effect, so the following statement-based rules for --binlog-ignore-db always apply in determining whether or not the statement is logged.

`DROP` is also a DDL which gets logged. So, does that mean there's no way? [On the contrary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log-setting.html):

> .... temporary tables are logged only when using statement-based replication, whereas with row-based replication they are not logged. With mixed replication, temporary tables are usually logged; exceptions happen with user-defined functions (UDFs) and with the UUID() function....

So, in short, for 'normal' tables this becomes next to impossible while working in a schema that is logged, however, `TEMPORARY`  tables are discarded in `ROW` based replication by default. This means: switch to `ROW` based replication, and you don't need to use a different schema for true temporary tables.

However, if you need to switch from `STATEMENT` / `MIXED` to `ROW` based replication, do check performance of this, and if you often do a bulk update (a lot of rows affected), your binlogs will quite a bit larger, as it will log every row changed rather then the single 'simple' `UPDATE`  statement which caused it.

Comment: I changed my my.cnf file by adding binlog_format = row. Restarted mysql and called the stored procedure again, but the temporary tables are still being recorded on the binary log. Checked the binlog-format value on mysql with the command: show variables like the "binlog_format", and now its is set to ROW (originally the format of the binlog was STATEMENT).

Comment: Hm, checked on version 5.5 & 5.6: (1) CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is not logged (2) DMLs on the temporary table are not logged (3) the only thing logged is `DROP /*!40005 TEMPORARY */ TABLE IF EXISTS temptablename`, which should be no problem as temporary table is session-specific, and the slave session itself will never have the table.

Comment: Errata: I have rechecked the binary log and yes indeed there is a big improvement!!  Now temporary tables are recorded when created and dropped, but it does not log the content inserted on them, which was the source of such a big binary logs. I guess I can live with that, but if there is a way to get rid of the creation / drop of the temporary tables on the binary logs, I'm glad to here it. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the `CREATE` being in there in 5.5.40, but good to hear at least your DML's don't show ;) I wouldn't know how to remove the `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE`, but it's close no a no-op on the slave.